Stripe.customers.cancel is not a function, Stripe version 14.18.0
When running Cypress tests, which call a cleanup function to remove users in Stripe, I get the following error:

Body: { "status": 500, "message": "Error while cleaning the stripe
test data", "error": "stripe.customers.cancel is not a function" }

In this issue on Github it says I need to be on version 9.x or above. However when running npm list in the directory where this package is installed, I can see I am using v14.18.0. I double-checked to see if there was a conflicting global package, but there does not seem to be. This is blocking me from testing at the moment, has anyone else experienced this or have any idea of where to look?
For the curious, this is the function called by Cypress for cleaning the test data:
const cleanAllCustomersExcept = async function cleanAllCustomersExcept(customersToKeep) {
  // Delete customers
  const customers = await stripe.customers.list();
  console.log(stripe.customers);
  const customersList = customers.data;
  await Promise.all(
    customersList.map(
      async (customer) => (customersToKeep.includes(customer.id)
        ? null
        : stripe.customers.cancel(customer.id)
          .then(() => {
            console.log(`Deleting customer ${customer.id}`);
          })),
    ),
  );

  if (customers.has_more) {
    return cleanAllCustomersExcept(customersToKeep);
  }
  console.log('Done removing all customers');
  return null;
}


The Customer API does not come with a Cancel method. If you look at Stripe's API reference here you can see this doesn't exist.
Similarly the Github issue you linked is about a completely different API called the Subscription API. That one does have a Cancel Subscription API method documented here.
Your code is incorrect and should not be calling the Cancel Customer API which doesn't exist. Maybe you meant to call the Delete Customer API which is documented here instead?

The thing is though that this was working until we went through a major upgrade of our packages and dependencies recently, but I did not see this change documented in their changelog anywhere.

I'm confident the Customer API never had a cancel method in stripe-node ever. If you look at the history of the file https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/master/src/resources/Customers.ts it doesn't seem to show anything like this at least.
